# How can I cut email addresses with sed?

Tags: sed, text-processing

I have the following emails.txt with:

```
tsar@gmail.com
c2m_@hotmail.com.es
c72@hotmail.com.es.com;es
m7_@hotmail.es.com
cm_@hotmail.com
@pepito.com
```

And a sed command to get

```
sed -n -r '/\w+@\w+\.\w+((\.\w+)*)?/p' emails.txt 

tsar@gmail.com
cm_@hotmail.com
```

But, it keeps displaying email with more than one .com

I don't want these emails :

```
c2m_@hotmail.com.es
c72@hotmail.com.es.com;es
m7_@hotmail.es.com 
@pepito.com
```

I'm stuck here and I have no clue about how to get it.

Comment: What emails do you want? Only those that are `user@domain.com`? Why do you want `@pepito.com`? How about `fulano@domain.es`? Are you trying to match only addresses whose domain is `foo.com` and nothing else?

Comment: Yes I just want the emails with user@domain.com, I don't want pepito cuz doesn't match with user@domain.com, but my command display user@domain.com.es.com etc

Answer (score 6):

With `sed`, you could do:

```
$ sed -nr '/^[^@]+@[^.]+\.com\s*$/p' file
tsar@gmail.com
cm_@hotmail.com
```

The regex looks for one or more non-`@` characters at the beginning of the line, then a `@`, then one or more non-`.` characters followed by `.com` and then 0 or more whitespace.

---

Other choices:

- Perl

  ```
  perl -ne 'print if /^[^@]+@[^.]+\.com\s*$/' file
  ```
- GNU `grep`

  ```
  grep -P '^[^@]+@[^.]+\.com\s*$' file
  ```
- POSIX `grep`

  ```
  grep -E '^[^@]+@[^.]+\.com\s*$' file
  ```
- `awk`

  ```
  awk '$0~/^[^@]+@[^.]+\.com\s*$/' file
  ```

Comment: There may not wihitespace at the end, but \r.

Comment: I would use egrep instead.

Comment: @Pilot6 not a problem, `\s` matches `\r` as well.

Comment: @Pilot6 sure, or various other tools. You can use the same regex on all of them. Just don't use `egrep`, that's been deprecated in favor of `grep -E` (see `man grep`).

Comment: I did not know that. I always use egrep, but I know that -E is same.

Comment: Where did you find that it was depreciated? When?

Comment: @Pilot6 many years now. It still works but it might stop doing so at any time. `egrep` is a link to `grep` on most systems still but there's no guarantee that it will continue to be so. Just read the first few lines of `man grep` or see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) (second paragraph of the description)

Comment: @terdon major typo in your regex..

Comment: @AvinashRaj that comment would have been more useful had you actually told me where the typo was.

Comment: I edited already... see the revisions.

Comment: @AvinashRaj oh,  man! Sorry, I was on mobile and couldn't see that you had edited so I was wondering why you hadn't fixed it instead of leaving a cryptic comment. Of course,  it turns out you had! Thanks and sorry for missing it.

Comment: No, need for sorry. You're my guru...

Answer (score 5):

I would use something like this :

```
sed -n -r '/\w+@\w+\.com$/p' emails.txt

tsar@gmail.com
cm_@hotmail.com
```

It will retrieve every email in format `user@xxx.com`

In case you need something more "universal" and not only `.com` but also `.fr` or `.uk` you can use :

```
sed -n -r '/\w+@\w+\.\w+$/p' emails.txt
```

This will retrieve every email in format `user@xxx.xxx`

Comment: I would take this one I understand this one much better thank you man.

Comment: So feel free to accept this answer if it actually answers and solves your problem... ;)

Answer (score 3):

The expression `((\.\w+)*)?` matches additional sequences of the form `.xyz` after the first domain. If you want to match *only* those addresses with a single domain, then you can enforce that by replacing it with `$` or (more robustly) `\s*$`

```
sed -n -r '/\w+@\w+\.\w+\s*$/p' emails.txt
```

to require that there is nothing (except possibly whitespace) between the first domain and the end of the line.